# How to transform a 60 fps video to a 25 fps?

Tags: hd-video

What would be the simplest way of transforming a movie recorded by a Canon 7D / 5D in 60 fps, to a 24 / 25 / 30 fps one, to get a slow-motion effect ?

Comment: This is a video question rather than photography: you'll likely have more luck over at the AV SE.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: That is true ...

Comment: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/convert-a-60-fps-video-to-a-24-film-video-is-it-possible

Answer (score 1):

Just load it into any video editing software such as Adobe Premiere Pro and adjust the clip speed. (Windows default Live Movie Maker does not allow you to do that but if I remember correctly you can do it in iMovie on the Mac)
After you adjust the speed export the movie as 24fps video.